# VB.net need starting help for HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm new to this HTMLAgilityPack thing and no idea on where or how to start, is there any way how to get the value of a specific part.

```
<tr>
                      <td style="background-color: #584c4c;">
                                                      <img src="https://bnltradingcorp.com/assets/member/image/bitactive.gif" style="height: 15%;width: 40px;">
                                                  </td>
                      <td><span class="small1">44915d6e6f<span class="elipsis" style="display:none;">2b620c533c3909c355b009_REPURCHASED</span><a class="elipsis" href="#"> ...</a></span></td>
                      <td><i class="fa fa-euro"></i> 1327</td>
                      <td><i class="fa fa-euro"></i> 9.29</td>
                      <td>Nov 8, 2018 02:32:45 PM</td>
```

I want to get only the "**1327**" and "**9.29**" part only, sorry for asking too much but really stuck in this part. By the normal means of getting innertext without using HTMLAgillityPack, it displays this all part "**44915d6e6f2b620c533c3909c355b009_REPURCHASED ... 1327 9.29 Nov 8, 2018 02:32:45 PM**", not the the specific part I want to extract.

Comment: It's a bit hard to give a concrete answer without knowing whole HTML, so if you can leave a link to website. Based ONLY on this posted part you can do it with SelectNodes(//i[@class='fa fa-euro'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Sub Grab()
    Dim WebDoc As New HtmlDocument
    WebDoc.LoadHtml(Webbrowser1.DocumentText)
    Dim Table As HtmlNode = WebDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@id='trading']/table/tbody") '// to search unlimited depth, @id to search for id element with name trading. /table/tbody to get inside completly
    Dim TableRows As HtmlNodeCollection = Table.SelectNodes("./tr") '. is to "Start from here" compared to begging of html. Grab only td elements, as there is  #text junk that we dont need
    Dim LastRow As HtmlNodeCollection = TableRows.Last.SelectNodes("./td") 'one way of selcting it, from many. Also exclude just #text with additional td selector
    For x = 2 To 3 'cells with index 2 and 3 are the ones we need
        Debug.Print(LastRow(x).InnerText.Trim) 'do something here
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I've just try pasting the code as initial on my button but there seems to be some errors in here.

https://snag.gy/r9XeYp.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that i forgot the " when I was typing. BTW, there is no html similar to the one in your question at https://bnltradingcorp.com/member/investment, you can't get html behind login like that.

Comment: By HTML, what do you mean by that?

Comment: You mean this one? If I'm not mistaken, sorry for the trouble sir. 
https://pastebin.com/Zad20Qqq

Comment: Really thank you so much for the time you stayed with me, greatly appreciate it sir. Works like a charm now.